# Nominal response - censored predictor

Tags: statistical-significance, ordinal-data, kruskal-wallis-test

What's the best way to study the association between nominal response (3 non-ordered categories) and one ordinal predictor variable (most observations are interval scaled, but some are censored (only known to be above x)) in smallish sample (50).

I think that Mantel-Haenszel row means score test (SAS) might be appropriate, but it's rarely used and equivalent to Kruskal-Wallis test and I would be more inclined to use Kruskal-Wallis test if my response was ordinal and predictor nominal, not the other way around. Do I have better options than Kruskal-Wallis test?